# How to align translated text below orignial text, vertically in latex?

Tags: latex

I have tried the following command :

```
\newcommand{\word}[2]{%
  \noindent
  \textcolor{black}{\fontsize{15}{18}\selectfont #1} 
  \\[1mm]
  \textcolor{gray}{\fontsize{11}{18}\selectfont #2}%
}
```

It displays the word as I desire, the problem is when I try to use two words to form a sentence. They do not render on the same line as I would like. The idea is to have the translation of a word below the word. I would like it to work for a longer text. Do you have any suggestions of how I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The code that does this is :

```
\newcommand{\word}[2]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    \textcolor{black}{\fontsize{15}{18}\selectfont #1} \\
    \textcolor{gray}{\fontsize{11}{18}\selectfont #2}
  \end{tabular}%
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**